# std::initializer_list does not allow narrowing

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this Vector class but its giving error.

```
narrowing conversion of ‘lst.std::initializer_list<_E>::size [with _E = double, std::initializer_list<_E>::size_type = long unsigned int]()’ from ‘std::initializer_list<double>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-fpermissive]
```

But if I change `sz{lst.size()}` to `sz{(int)lst.size()}` it's OK.
Would appreciate if any one could please put some light on this.
I am using (Code:Blocks IDE) enabled C++0x in my IDE.
Compiler
GCC (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <initializer_list>  // std::initializer_list
    class Vector
    {
            double* elem;
            int sz;
    public:
            Vector(int s):elem{new double[s]}, sz{s}
            {
                for(int i = 0; i != s; i++)
                    elem[i] = 0;
            }

            ~Vector()
            {
                delete[] elem;
            }

            double& operator[] (int i);
            int size() const;
            void push_back(double);

            //Compilation ERROR: 
            Vector(initializer_list<double> lst):elem{new double[lst.size()]},sz{lst.size()}
            {
                    //copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), elem);
            }

             //THIS IS OK   
            /* Vector(initializer_list<double> lst):elem{new double[lst.size()]},sz{(int)lst.size()}
            {
                    //copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), elem);
            } */
    };
```

Comment: Can you state the question more specifically? Are you asking what a narrowing conversion is? Did you already search for that term? — also note that `initializer_list` has nothing to do with the error at hand; it's only tangentially involved because you called `size()` on one.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you ask for an implicit conversion of `lst.size()` which is of type `size_t` (e.g. a 64 unsigned integer) to an `int` (e.g. 32 bit signed). In the context of brace initialization, this is a narrowing conversion which is potentially dangerous.

> [dcl.init.list] A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion ... from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type,...

Narrowing conversion rules are only used for braced initializer lists, i.e. for `int a{1}`, and not for the classic initialization which used `()`, i.e. for `int a(1)`.

---

So there are three ways out:

1. Use `std::size_t` as the type for `sz`. `sz` indicates the length of a memory block, so `std::size_t` is the correct type. (recommend)
2. Use explicit conversion `sz{static_cast<int>(lst.size())}`.
3. Use `()` instead of `{}` in the constructor. (not recommend)

   ```
     Vector(initializer_list<double> lst)
     : elem(new double[lst.size()]), sz(lst.size())
     //                               ^^^        ^^^
   ```

Comment: Thanks Danvil that was useful explanation.

Comment: @GopalkrishnaMudaliar Consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem.